# convert .class file/s to .java file/s of .jar file

Tags: java, class, java-me, mobile, jar

how can i convert?? .class file to .java file/s to see source code of .jar file (which is mobile app on midp 2.0)

how can i convert ?

Comment: looking for any tools for doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Java decompiler like [this](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a decompiler such as JAD.  However, if the code has been obfuscated, this may not be very useful.

Comment: there are some hex code editor available, using that you can get back source code of java

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answers:  recently, a new wave of decompilers is coming, namely Procyon, CFR, JD, Fernflower

Here's a list of decompilers as of 2015:

- Procyon
- CFR
- JD
- Fernflower

You may test above mention decompilers online, no installation required and make your own educated choice. 
**Modern java decompilers in the cloud:**  http://www.javadecompilers.com/